# prefixing asset path for files in Symfony2 and Twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig, assets

I upoad my files to `web/files/images/` and i'm trying to link them using `asset` function:

```
<img src='{{ asset(article.image) }}'/>
```

but this produces URLs like `/img1.jpg`
I need to prefix (setting a base folder) asset URLs to force it to make `/files/images/img1.jpg`
How can I prefix `asset` urls?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While you could easily introduce a new twig variable for that purpose (i.e. in your base template) ...

```
{% set asset_base = '//files/images' %}
```

... or create a static global twig variable ...

```
# app/config/config.yml
twig:
    globals:
        asset_base: //files/images
```

... and afterwards use it inside i.e. the `src` attribute of your `img` tag ...

```
<img src='{{ asset_base }}{{ asset(article.image) }}'/>
```

... **symfony2 already provides this functionality** in form of the `assets_base_urls` directive:

```
# app/config/config.yml
framework:
    templating:
        assets_base_urls:
            http:   [http://domain/files/images]
            ssl:    [https://domain/files/images]
```

You can aswell set the base urls both at once by providing a protocol-relative url:

```
framework:
    templating:
        assets_base_urls: //files/images
```

More information about the directive can be found in the documentation chapter **[FrameworkBundle Configuration#assets-base-urls](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#assets-base-urls)**.

Answer (score 3):

Note that since symfony 2.7 the *assets_base_urls* solution from @nifr will only work with valid urls, not with relative pathes.

See here https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/14332

The solution for > 2.7 is to use the new assets component for relative base path as prefix.

```
framework:
    assets:
        base_path: 'assets'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to prefix all assets, the asset helper provides another really nice way to do this using packages.

Packages have a name and can have other settings, such as the version and the base path. You configure packages in the configuration and you can set the name of the package to use in the second argument of the asset function.

In your case:

```
framework:
    templating:
        packages:
            images:
                base_url: /web/files/images # can also be scheme specific
```

And then in you template:

```
<img src="{{ asset('...', 'images'). }}">
```

More information: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/templating/helpers/assetshelper.html#multiple-packages

Comment: What do you mean by "scheme specific"?